# Set Android Theme.Light for Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I am trying to set the android **Theme.Light** theme for my alert dialog, but with no success so far. After reading a few tutorials I gathered that using **AlertDialog.Builder** we cannot set the theme directly in the constructor (atleast in API level 7).

The alternate solution that I found is using a **ContextThemeWrapper**, which everyone assured would solve my problem. So I coded something like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.popup_theme));
```

I described my theme in the values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="back_color">#ffffffff</color>
<style name="popup_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/back_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/back_color</item>
</style>
```

Unfortunately I still get the default **Theme.Dialog.Alert** theme. Can anyone tell me why? Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**: 
If you do not know the answer to my question, please vote up. I have a bad habit of posting questions which get stuck :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change `parent="android:Theme.Light"` to `parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"`

Comment: Corrected it. Still no change.

Comment: does it work? also, how do you set it for actionBarSherlock dialogs?

Answer (score 4):

This took me a while to figure out as well.

The issue at hand is that Theme.Light and Theme.Holo.Light and such are designed around the activity. A dialog theme needs to be based around a theme such as @android:style/Theme.Dialog which contains properties specific to dialogs.

```
<style name="popup_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Try overriding the Theme.Dialog using things like:

```
<item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceInverse</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<style name="popup_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parent="android:style/Theme.Light"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. And it worked for me

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog);
```