# How to change the color of DatePicker Dialog

Tags: android

I like to change the color of DatePicker Dialog. I load the dialog as

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

       @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
       public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
      }

      public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
           // Do something with the date chosen by the user


      }


}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");//show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

When it load the dialog, it is white color background. How can I change to display color as show in the second picture?
Thanks[image][image]

Comment: Checkout the answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729697/set-android-theme-light-for-alert-dialog

Comment: That one uses AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.popup_theme)); and change the theme. But for me is I use newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");How can I change the theme?

Answer (score 6):

As per your query you have to create custom dialog theme and set in `custom_theme.xml` Now simply set as per your `API` version.

First, in values add a themes.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Any customizations for your app running on pre-3.0 devices here -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then, create a directory with the name "values-v11" (Android 3.0+ ) in the res directory and put a themes.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- Any customizations for your app running on 3.0+ devices here -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Finally, create a directory with the name "values-v14" (Android 4.0+) in the res directory and create a themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Any customizations for your app running on 4.0+ devices here -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

[For More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681648/how-to-use-holo-light-theme-and-fall-back-to-light-on-pre-honeycomb-devices) check out the link and follow it.

Hope you get some idea form them and solve your issue.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would try. For Android <= 2.3 (API 10 / v10), have your theme extend from the default android light theme, in Android 3.0 (API 11 / v11) and up, I would extend from the holo light theme. You can see how to do this here: 
[How to use Holo.Light theme, and fall back to 'Light' on pre-honeycomb devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681648/how-to-use-holo-light-theme-and-fall-back-to-light-on-pre-honeycomb-devices)

I'm not 100% sure this will change your alert dialog, since I haven't used the light theme extensively, so you may need to edit an attribute or two from the light theme to get the background of the edit text to be light.